# Fast way to write pairs int-double to binary file on disk

Tags: rcpp, ofstream

What I tried:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void write_indval(const char * filename,
                  const IntegerVector& i,
                  const NumericVector& x) {

  ofstream myFile(filename, ios::out | ios::binary);

  const int * pI = i.begin();
  const double * pX = x.begin();
  int K = i.size();

  for (int k = 0; k < K; k++, pI++, pX++) {
    myFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(pI), 4);
    myFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(pX), 8);
  }

  myFile.close();
}
```

If I try it in R:

```
N <- 1e8
i <- sample(1000, N, replace = TRUE)
x <- runif(N)
system.time(
  write_indval("test.bin", i, x)
)
```

It takes 16 secs to write this 1.1 GB data.
The data written seems to be what I want, but I am writing at 72 MB / sec.
I think I can write at 300 MB / sec on my computer. So, anyone knows a faster alternative to this function?

Comment: Maybe study closely what packages `fst` and `qs` do? I think at that level you need to worry about L1 and L2 memory, blocksizes, and a whole lot more.

Comment: Also, as the two vectors are the same length, why not 1) open a file, 2) wite the entire `int` vector in one `fwrite()` operation followed by the entire `double` vector.  If you wanted to be fancy, you could pre-pend a header describe `rows`, `cols`, and the datatypes that follow.  Also, consider `saveRDS()` with and without compression.

Comment: I'm using memory-mapping on this afterwards, this is why I need a simple binary file. Also, I would like to append new values afterwards, this is why I can't have all ints and then all doubles, but prefer to have int-double pairs together.

Comment: Sure. "Tradeoffs".  Such is life.  Given these requirements, expecting 300mb/sec may not be realistic.  Or ... think outside that old box.  Maybe one csv with meta data (rows, cols, types, ...) and then one binary file per column. Trivial to seek, append, mmap, ...